# Looping through API with hbs

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js, express-handlebars, handlebarshelper

I'm coming from ejs. I had a function to loop though my API data like this:

```
<p><% data["Search"].forEach(function(movies){ %>
    <li><strong><%= movies["Title"] %></strong> - <%= movies["Year"] %> - <%= movies["Type"] %></li>
<% }) %></p>
```

How can I use hbs to do the same? I tried this:

```
<div>
    {{#each data}}
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                {{Title}}
            </div>
        </div>
    {{/each}}
</div>
```

but it doesn't display anything.

Here is my **app.js**:

```
const   express     = require("express"),
        request     = require("request"),
        bodyParser  = require("body-parser"); 

var     app         = express();

app.use(express.static("public")); 
app.set("view engine", "hbs"); 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 

app.get("/moviesearch", function(req, res){
    res.render("moviesearch");
});


app.get("/movieResults", function (req, res) {
    var user = req.query.getValue;
    var url = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=" + user + "&apikey=...";
    request(url, function (error, response, body) {
        var data = JSON.parse(body);
        res.render("API_Results", { data: data });
    });
});
```

How can I loop through those values on my API_Result.hbs?

**Example of search: Broomsticks**

```
{
Search: [
{
Title: "Bedknobs and Broomsticks",
Year: "1971",
imdbID: "tt0066817",
Type: "movie",
Poster: "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTUxMTY3MTE5OF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNTQ0ODgxMzE@._V1_SX300.jpg",
},
{
Title: "When Broomsticks Were King",
Year: "2001",
imdbID: "tt1418965",
Type: "movie",
Poster: "N/A",
},
],
totalResults: "5",
Response: "True",
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please look into below code. you have to run a loop as we do it inside js.

```html
<div>
    {{#each data.Search}}
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                {{Title}}
            </div>
        </div>
    {{/each}}
</div>
```

Comment: Id I do that it still doesn't display it:

   <div>
    {{#each data}}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            {{data.Title}}
        </div>
    </div>
    {{/each}}
</div>

Comment: In your js file res.render("API_Results", { data: data }); should be replaced
res.render("API_Results", { data: data.Search }); or replace {{#each item in data}} to {{#each item in data.Search}}

Comment: If I do this: <div>
    {{#each data.Search}}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <li>{{movies.Title}}</li>
        </div>
    </div>
    {{/each}}
</div>

It actually displays how many movies in terms of li, but no data

Comment: try <div> {{#each movies in data.Search}} <div class="row"> <div class="col-md-12"> <li>{{movies.Title}}</li> </div> </div> {{/each}} </div>

Comment: that gives error: API_Results.hbs: Must pass iterator to #each

Comment: I got it working, fix your answer to this: <div>
    {{#each data.Search}}
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <li>{{Title}}</li>
            </div>
        </div>
    {{/each}}
</div>

If you want me to select it as final, if not I'll publish it. Thanks for the help

Comment: Great so the actual issue was passing the whole response object instead of Search array inside the response object. I was suggesting you based on EmberJS way of using Handlebars :)